# jenkins - which plugin copy artifacts and can get as input user credentials to remote machine

Tags: deployment, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, autodeploy

Is it me or there isn't Jenkins plugin that simply can take your DLLs and copy it to a remote machine (UNC) with a predefined domain user password?

I think I miss something here, can't perform simple deployment to a machine that demands those credentials (ArtifactsDeployer etc.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [CIFS Publisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CIFS-Publisher+Plugin) plugin provides the feature you're looking for.

> This plugin uploads build artifacts to repository sites using CIFS (SMB) protocol. First you should define CIFS shares in the Hudson global configuration page. After that you can refer to the shares using a select list in your project configuration.

---

**Update** Sorry, I just noticed that CIFS Publisher is deprecated in favor of the [Publish over CIFS](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin) plugin, which is part of a common collection of publisher plugins for different protocols. In any case, the 'copy to remote CIFS share' feature is supported.